# Inserting a row to the beginning of tables

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to insert a row to beginning of many tables the

```
$('table > tbody > tr:first').before('<tr><td>Stuff</td></tr>');
```

is adding new `tr` only to the first table and the

```
$("tbody").each(function() {
      $('table > tbody > tr:first').before('<tr><td>Stuff</td></tr>');
    });
```

is adding all new `tr`s to the first table again.  How can I fix this?

```js
$("tbody").each(function() {
  $('table > tbody > tr:first').before('<tr><td>Stuff</td></tr>');
});

$('table > tbody > tr:first').before('<tr><td>Stuff</td></tr>');
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>February</td>
      <td>$80</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>February</td>
      <td>$80</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>February</td>
      <td>$80</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>February</td>
      <td>$80</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `$(this)` to give reference to the each table.

```js
$("tbody ").each(function() {
  $(this).before('<tr><td>Stuff</td></tr>');
});
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>February</td>
      <td>$80</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>February</td>
      <td>$80</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>February</td>
      <td>$80</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>February</td>
      <td>$80</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**P.S** - If you want it inside `tbody` you can do it using `$(this).find("tr:first").before('<tr><td>Stuff</td></tr>');`

Comment: And you've inserted it into the table, but outside the tbody. Ooops. You'll want to find the first row of that tbody, and use before() to insert before THAT.

Answer (score 2):

```js
$("tbody").each(function() {
  // I don't want to insert before the tbody,
  //  I want to insert before the first row.
  $(this).find("tr:first").before('<tr><td>Stuff</td></tr>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>February</td>
      <td>$80</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>February</td>
      <td>$80</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>February</td>
      <td>$80</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>February</td>
      <td>$80</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using the same selector, not the `tbody`.

```
$("tbody").each(function() {
  $(this).before('<tr><td>Stuff</td></tr>');
});
```

Comment: You did the same -- you've inserted it before the tbody tag. You'll probably want to find the first tr el within that tbody, and insert it before that.